# Prompt is asking question 2 times. How can I fix this?

Tags: batch-file

I tried to make a check to see if the EULA is set to true in eula.txt but when typing true it asks again and I have to type true again.

I tried on Windows 10 and using a .cmd file instead of .bat (the same thing)

```
@echo off
SET jarFileName=server.jar
SET jarFileUrl=https://cdn.getbukkit.org/spigot/spigot-1.12.2.jar
SET memory=4G
SET startColor=0F
SET errorColor=CF

rem Colors and things
color %startColor%
MODE CON COLS=136 LINES=36

rem Start server
:checkEULA1
if exist eula.txt (
goto checkEULA2
) else (
echo eula=false>eula.txt
goto checkEULA2
)

:checkEULA2
>nul findstr /c:"eula=true" eula.txt && (
  rem EULA true
  goto start
) || (
  rem EULA not true
  echo Do you accept the EULA? Type true if you do.
  set /p eula=
  echo eula=%eula% >eula.txt
  goto checkEULA1
)

:start
pause
if exist %jarFileName% (
    java -version >nul 2>&1|| cls&&color %errorColor%&&echo Please install Java and add it to PATH. Usually the 64 bit JDK works better. && goto exit
    cls
    java -Xmx%memory% -jar %jarFileName% nogui
) else (
    cls
    echo %jarFileName% not detected. Downloading...
    powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%jarFileurl%', '%jarFileName%')"
    echo Done!
    echo.
    echo Press any key to start server... && pause>nul && cls && goto start
)

rem Exit
:exit
echo.
color %errorColor%
echo.
echo Press any key to exit... && pause>nul && exit
```

I want it to only ask the question once. No errors I can see.

Comment: You'll need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) in the line `echo eula=%eula% >eula.txt`...

Comment: What happens if the end user, for example, `just presses the enter key`, or enters `Not true` or `untrue`? _Would the current code allow them to continue, even though they've technically not accepted the terms?_ Also, you're setting a variable and trying to use its value within the same block of code. _You may wish to look into delayed expansion_.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could probably do this a little bit simpler:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "startColor=0F"
Set "errorColor=CF"

Set "jarFileName=server.jar"
Set "jarFileUrl=https://cdn.getbukkit.org/spigot/spigot-1.12.2.jar"
Set "memory=4G"

FindStr /I "^eula=true$" "eula.txt" >NUL 2>&1||(Color %errorColor%
    Choice /M "Do you accept the EULA"
    If ErrorLevel 2 Exit /B 1
    (Echo eula=true)>eula.txt)

ClS
Mode 136,36
Color %startColor%
Rem Start server
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `eula` variable is only set after exiting the `findstr` function.

An easy solution is to create another function and `goto` it:

```sh
:checkEULA1
    if exist eula.txt (
        goto checkEULA2
    ) else (
        echo eula=false>eula.txt
        goto checkEULA2
    )

:checkEULA2
    findstr /c:"eula=true" "eula.txt" >nul 2>&1 && (
        rem EULA true
        goto start
    ) || (
        rem EULA not true
        set /p eula= Do you accept the EULA? Type true if you do: 
        goto setEULA
    )

:setEULA
    echo eula=%eula%>eula.txt
    goto checkEULA1
```